# How do I properly use conditional execution to draw a circle based on input?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, conditional-statements, execution

My end goal is to make a function where in the end you have to finds and one button and when you press the button it adds the 2 numbers together and if that number is less than 5 it draws a red circle and if it is bigger it draws a yellow one. The problem I am having is I do not know how to make my two inputs be defined as X. I want it so that when X is < 5 it draws a red circle.

Here is how far I have gotten so far.

HTML:
    
    
    
    
    ConditionalPractice

## Colors

```
 Number: <input id="numberOne" /> <br/>                                         

Number: <input id="numberTwo" /> <br/>                                         


<input type="button" value="Your Color!" onclick="decideColor()" />            

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>                       

<script src="js/main.js"></script>                                             
</body>                                                                        
</html>
```

and Java: 
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

```
function decideColor() {

var numberOne= document.getElementbyId("numberOne");

var numberTwo= document.getElementbyId("numberTwo");

}

//#F04331 red #006400 green  #FAE157 yellow
function animate(){
ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

if( x < 5 ) {
ctx.fillstyle = "#F04331"
fillCircle(10, 10, 30)
}



function fillCircle(x, y, radius) {
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();}
}
```

Comment: To store valus of input fields use:
var numberOne= document.getElementbyId("numberOne").value;
var numberTwo= document.getElementbyId("numberTwo").value;

Don't use x in if, but this:
if(numberOne > 5 || numberTwo > 5)
{
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzvqfb3e/1/). You need to define your fields as input type="number". Then read the input, calculate them and based on what the result is, pass a different color string to your animate function, which now takes a parameter color. You also need to really learn to get your function and property names right. You were using `fillstyle`but it is called `fillStyle`.

```
function animate(color){

   var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

   ctx.fillstyle = color;

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(10, 10, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.closePath();
   ctx.fill();
}
```